# Проблема с запуском сайта через OpenServer

Tags: php, openserver

Я пытаюсь запустить через вспомогательное окно OpenServer, но быстрого доступа в проектах нет, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Я новичок, не ругайте.
[image: здесь папки самого сайта]

Comment: и чего не работает то? по скриншоту проводника вам тут ничего не ответят. Обычно добалвяют домен через Настройки  - Домены.

Comment: Эх, коммент выше поддерживаю, покажи, что получаете при переходе openServer->Мои сайты->localhost, вывод из браузера, ну и настройки Домены.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуй перезагрузить OpenServer.
2. Измени название папки и перезагрузи OpenServer.
3. Создай новую папку, создай там index.php, а потом проверь, выводятся ли данные на странице. Если да, то постепенно загружай остальные файлы, попутно проверяя, не сломалось ли чего.